# For arrays in Firestore, is there any downside to searching it for string vs int values?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I noticed that Firestore allows arrays and some operations on them like containsAny([...]).

I'm thinking of having a array of values, but the values I'll be putting in are UUIDs (strings). So, it may look like this:

```
MyCollection {
  categoryIds List<String>
}
```

And I'll do operations like `where(categoryIds, containsAny(uuid1, uuid2))`

Is there a performance hit vs if I had stored numbers instead of string?DOes it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore queries are generally based on indexes, so I doubt there's any performance difference between the two.

Also note: Firestore "arrays" are ABSOLUTELY NOT ARRAYS. They are ORDERED LISTS, generally in the order they were added to the array. The SDK presents them to the CLIENT as arrays, but Firestore itself does not STORE them as actual arrays - THE NUMBER YOU SEE IN THE CONSOLE is the order, not an index. Matching elements in an array (arrayContains, e.g.) requires matching the WHOLE element - if you store an ordered list of objects, you CANNOT query the "array" on sub-elements.

The client SDKs generally present the values in the arrays/"ordered lists" to you as an array - which has more to do with most languages not having a primitive element that is an ordered list.

Comment: "based on indexes" means there really isn't any searching involved, as such - they just used the value to match a point in the index, depending on "==", ">", etc